# DateTime::modify setting date but not time

Tags: php, datetime

I am using the following to create a date I can work with. I want the date to jump to next Tuesday and retain the time that is originally stored in **$start**. Currently it is only jumping forward to next Tuesdays date but it is not saving the time. The time is reset to midnight.

```
$day="Tuesday";
$start=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
$firstOccurrence= $start->getTimestamp();
$nextOccurence=$start->modify("next $day");
```

Comment: You don't need to use createFromFormat() here. new DateTime($start) will do.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same result. 

$start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') outputs 2014-06-03 08:00:00
$nextOccurence->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') outputs 2014-06-09 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You need to transfer the times from the original object. Also, I would recommend using clone to avoid side effects:-

```
$start = '2014-03-20 18:23:15';
$day="Tuesday";
$start=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
$nextOccurence = clone $start;
$nextOccurence->modify("next $day")->setTime((int)$start->format('H'), (int)$start->format('i'), (int)$start->format('s'));
var_dump($nextOccurence);
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/EDG35).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up storing the hour and minutes of the day separately and then adding it to the new date.